# Traffic analysis for individual questions

Tags: support

I know this feature exists for aggregate data but I am wondering if it is also available on the individual question level and if more detailed queries are possible.

Is there any way to see how users came to click on a particular question?
E.g. was it a hot network question? In this case what percentage of users came from which SE?

Or did they find it on Google? In this case is it possible to get a breakdown of what search phrases they were using?

The current motivation for this question is to find out source of traffic for [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/15840/a-law-against-selling-any-house-cheaper-than-it-was-bought-for-what-consequence) that got 12K views in 4 days, for [this question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/15935/desperate-grad-students-who-cant-figure-out-this-search-and-matching-problem) which has almost no keywords but got 330 views in 8 hours.

Update:

 After 18 hours the question with almost no keywords is at 650 views. How do people find it...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Re: Your "update" question**

I was under the impression that "**Desperate grad student**" is a very popular keyword, all over the world. It transcends continents and cultures, race and religion, if not time itself.

Comment: I'd say it is a frequent, not a popular phenomenon. And why would people google for it...?

Comment: @denesp Because they find themselves in the same position.